# Getting SOLR exception when initialise apparel store data from Admin console

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris and trying to publish a new store and followed relevant steps. The build was successful. When i try to initailse the Apparel Store, i am continuously getting SO[enter link description here][1]LR exceptions. Attched exception logs for reference

> ERROR
>   [update-apparel-ukIndex-cronJob::de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob]
>   (update-apparel-ukIndex-cronJob) [LukeSolrIndexStatisticsProvider]
>   Could not get last index time for [Product] INFO   | jvm 1    | main
>   | 2016/04/21 14:02:09.120 |
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.solr.exceptions.SolrServiceException:
>   Could not check for a remote solr core [master_apparel-uk_Product] due
>   to Server refused connection at: http://localhost:8983/solr

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the `solrserver` extension declared in your `localextensions.xml` file in order for hybris to automatically startup a local solr server. If you have that but still get the error, maybe you have some firewall settings? You could post your `localextensions.xml` file and the `local.properties` file, both located in the `hybris/config` folder...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.. Now i have added solrserver extension and server is starting up well.
I am trying to publish a new store now. I followed below steps
1.) run ant modulegen
2.) Select default template as accelerator, name and package
3.) Added the entry of the newly created 6 folders into localextensions.xml exculding test
4.) Run ant clean all
5,) Start Server

After all this when i try to hot the URL
http://localhost:9001/kuldeepstorefront/?site = electronics

i am getting 404 error, (page not found). Can some one suggest what step i am missing?

Comment: only `ant clean all` won't do it, you need at least an update running system (you can do that from the hac, usually at `http://localhost:9001/platform/update` ) or preferrably even an `ant initialize` to reinitialize after you added/created extensions.

Comment: actually my last comment might not be true (item.xml changes require an update running system though), but its always worth trying if that helps.